# What virtual keyboards are available which are most touch-friendly?

Tags: software-recommendation, multi-touch, wacom, touchscreen

I've installed the 12.0.4 beta on my Dell latitude XT2 and although I can navigate Dash with my fingers, but the Onboard onscreen keyboard does not pop up when I want to search for applications in Dash.

I've also tried Caribou but it gets in the way far too much, it pops up when i want to input in the URL bar in Firefox but does not go away when i want it to! I would also try Florence if it wasn't a dependency hell to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

XVKBD is a great and very customizable on-screen keyboard with features such as word completion. From [XVKBD's website:](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/)

> xvkbd is a virtual (graphical) keyboard program for X Window System which provides facility to enter characters onto other clients (softwares) by clicking on a keyboard displayed on the screen. This may be used for systems without a hardware keyboard such as kiosk terminals or handheld devices. This program also has facility to send characters specified as the command line option to another client.

I would give this a try.